# Show spinner on print and download pdf

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I want to show spinner while the client waits for the backend to send a response with base64string and then show it to print like pdf. I use simple JavaScript for this in my Angular application. All logic for spinner is implemented. The problem is when I call the print method looks like it is happening very fast or not waiting for foreach loop to finish.If I comment foreach logic and removed false to end spinner was working.

```
    print() {

    //Must start spinner
    this.sharedService.loadingSpinner = true;

    selectedDocuments.forEach((x) => {
      this.calculator.printPolicy(policyId, x).subscribe((res) => {
        const base64str = res["bBlob_PDF"];
        const binary = atob(base64str.replace(/\s/g, ""));
        const len = binary.length;
        const buffer = new ArrayBuffer(len);
        let view = new Uint8Array(buffer);
        for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
          view[i] = binary.charCodeAt(i);
        }
        let theBlob = new Blob([view], { type: "application/pdf" });
        let URLObject = URL.createObjectURL(
          new Blob([view], { type: "application/pdf" })
        );
        window.open(URLObject, "_blank");
        let a = document.createElement("a");
        a.href = URLObject;
        a.download = "MyHome_" + policyId + ".pdf";
        //a.click();
      });      
    });
    //Must stop the spinner when all is finished
    this.sharedService.loadingSpinner = false;
    this.hasBeenPrinted = true;
  }
```

Comment: Subscribe is the async process. JS is a sequential language. I think the code after your foreach will execute before your printpolicy() is completed with all 'x' . so try to put it inside the foreach loop by looking for last element and terminate the process on condition

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that by chaining all the print observables together, using `forkJoin`, then subscribe to its observable which will emit value only once all the sub observables have been completed, the you can stop the spinner within this subscribe function.

Try the following:

```js
print() {

  //Must start spinner
  this.sharedService.loadingSpinner = true;

  forkJoin(
    selectedDocuments.map((x) =>
      this.calculator.printPolicy(policyId, x).pipe(
        tap((res) => {
          const base64str = res['bBlob_PDF'];
          const binary = atob(base64str.replace(/\s/g, ''));
          const len = binary.length;
          const buffer = new ArrayBuffer(len);
          let view = new Uint8Array(buffer);
          for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            view[i] = binary.charCodeAt(i);
          }
          let theBlob = new Blob([view], { type: 'application/pdf' });
          let URLObject = URL.createObjectURL(
            new Blob([view], { type: 'application/pdf' })
          );
          window.open(URLObject, '_blank');
          let a = document.createElement('a');
          a.href = URLObject;
          a.download = 'MyHome_' + policyId + '.pdf';
          //a.click();
        })
      )
    )
  ).subscribe(() => {
    // Stop the spinner when all is finished
    this.sharedService.loadingSpinner = false;
    this.hasBeenPrinted = true;
  });
}
```

Comment: This is a very good solution but in Angular 11 forkJoin was deprecated

Comment: Just some overloads of the `forkJoin` are deprecated, not the function itself. I will try to change my answer to use the not deprecated overload. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I already used a valid overload, it's not deprecated. [This](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/beeeb7bdc3b09524bdd6c59ff40ed80ac932076a/src/internal/observable/forkJoin.ts#L34) overload is used from `RxJS@6`, and [this](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/6f0e853a86e6db1ab321ff077c95e6b1d88fd3df/src/internal/observable/forkJoin.ts#L29) from `RxJS@7` and both of them are not deprecated.